# quincykit not able to symbolicate

Tags: php, iphone, ios

I am using quincykit to get the crash reports of ios app, I am able to get the crash files to my server. I can see the crash report. I tired to symbolicate it. But it gives me same as input(contents in original crash file)

1. I am able to get the crash file in 'local' folder in mac.
2. I am able to post the content from mac to server (It is working)
3. I guess the problem is in symbolicatecrash.pl, Here my input and output are coming same.
4. I added .app file and .app.dSYM file in same directory as symbolicatecrash.pl.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely don't have the correct dSYM for the build that caused the crash at all or in a path that Spotlight indexed.

The following page explains how to find out if you have the correct dSYM available: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/how-tos-faq/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i got the code from your github repository thanks for the code too...How can i make sure that I have correct dSYM ? ..I am not from ios background, I am a php developer

Comment: For release builds always use the Xcode archive feature to build. Otherwise every time you do a build, the dSYM is overwritten.

Comment: I placed the `.app` and `.app.dSYM` in the same folder as `symbolicatecrash.pl` file, is that correct ? It is mensioned about the folder with app name and version do i need to follow like that ?

Comment: I don't get what you are talking about. Please test if the dSYM has the same UUID as the crash report references. This is described in the linked webpage above. All you need is described in there. If symbolication doesn't work, then most likely the dSYM is **NOT** the correct one!